# Put the access callback function in a separated file

Tags: 7, routes, hooks

When I put the access callback function in a separated file I get an error.

```
$items['node/%node/join'] = array(
    'title' => t('Join Game'),
    'page callback' => 'agentweb_membership_join',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access callback' => '_agentweb_membership_join_access',
    'access arguments' => array(1),
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'file' => 'join.page.inc',
);
```

When I put `_agentweb_membership_join_access()` in `join.page.inc` I get an error, but when I move it to `agentweb_membership.module` everything works correctly.

Why does it happen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The access callback has to be in the same file; the file passed in the "file" property gets loaded only if the access callback returns `TRUE`. The only other "solution" is to use an include at the top of your module.

Comment: It appears the same is true for a 'title callback' function, which can be used to set a dynamic page title. It only seems to work when in the .module file or if you do an include.